# How do you read an integer from JTextField and use it in more methods?

Tags: java, swing, numbers, jtextfield

I've the following problem:
I need to read a integer from my JTextField and use it again in a painting method (paintComponent). With this integer I need to set the size of the square. I've added a listener to the textfield and created a class for it to get the value as an integer, followed by repaint. But the square stays the same size.

```
import javax.swing.*; 
import java.awt.*; 
import java.awt.event.*;  

class MouseDemoOld extends JPanel implements MouseListener 
  {
  int x, y; // location of mouse
  int sx, sy; // size of shape 
 JFrame frame;
 JTextField tf;

 void buildIt() 
 {     
   frame = new JFrame("MouseDemo");
   tf = new JTextField("100");
   frame.add(this);
   frame.add(tf, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
   this.x = 150;
   this.y = 150;
   this.sx = 10;
   this.sy = sx;

    HandlerClass handler = new HandlerClass();
    tf.addActionListener(handler);

    this.addMouseListener(this); // MouseDemo is its own MouseListener!  
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(300, 300);
    frame.setLocation(200, 200);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    }

  public void paintComponent(Graphics g) 
  {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor( Color.blue );
    g.fillRect(x - sx/2, y - sy/2, sx, sy);
  }    

  // the method from MouseListener we're interested in this time
  public void mousePressed( MouseEvent e) 
  {
    // add code to update x and y 
    x = e.getX();
    y = e.getY();
    repaint();
  }   

  public void mouseReleased( MouseEvent e) { }
  public void mouseClicked( MouseEvent e) { }
  public void mouseEntered( MouseEvent e) { }
  public void mouseExited( MouseEvent e) { }

  private class HandlerClass implements ActionListener
  {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {
      if(event.getSource()==tf)
      {
        int text = Integer.parseInt(tf.getText());
        int sx = text;
        int sy = text;
        repaint();
      }
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
    new MouseDemoOld().buildIt(); 
  }
}
```

Comment: you are creating new variables inside your action listener object and not using the the ones from your MouseDemoOld object.

Comment: because you create a HandlerClass object it has no idea about your MouseDemoOld object's member variables sx, sy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not redefine `sx` and `sy` in `HandlerClass`. Since `HandlerClass` is an inner class it can access the `sx` and `sy` fields of the outer class. So, just remove the `int` keyword from both variables in `HandlerClass`. Also, you want to catch `NumberFormatException` when calling `Integer.parseInt` in case a non-integer is entered into the text field.